# Sharepoint stopped receiving incoming emails

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

SharePoint server  stopped receiving incoming emails from Exchange, no emails showing in onerous/drop,bad mail folder. Tried IIS restart, SMTP service is running bounce back message:
Delivery is delayed to these recipients or groups
Diagnostic information for administrators:

```
Generating server: Exchsngedomainserver.com
Receiving server: sharepoint 2016
```

lazyapproval@Domain.com
Server at sharepoint 2016  returned '400
4.4.7 Message delayed'

8/27/2020 8:35:01 PM - Server at sharepoint 2016  returned '451 4.4.397 Error communicating with target host. -> 421 4.2.1 Unable to connect -> SocketConnectionRefused: Socket error code 10061'
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Whether this issue occurs in only one document library or in the all libraries? If it happens in one document, you could create a new document then have a test.

Please restart SMTP service in windows services and Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Incoming E-Mail Service in the services on server. Re-enable incoming email settings in central administration.

And you could review ULS for incoming email issues open the ULS log in ULS Viewer. There may be more useful clues.

Similar questions:

[Delivery is delayed to these recipients or groups](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/9a8a6172-c00d-4d66-9b43-d855846122d3/delivery-is-delayed-to-these-recipients-or-groups?forum=exchangesvrsecuremessaging)

[Incoming email Delivery has failed to these recipients or groups](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1166a43d-fcb5-4e3a-be44-27978fa0a62c/incoming-email-delivery-has-failed-to-these-recipients-or-groups?forum=sharepointadmin)

[Delivery has failed to these recipients or groups](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/322444-delivery-has-failed-to-these-recipients-or-groups)